Direction of normal vector in Bounday Condition Problem
This is a problem from from my text.The only thing where I am stuck here is the direction of normal vector.What I want to know is whether there is any convention for the direction of normal vector.Should it be from region 2 to region 1 or from region 1 to region 2.
